# Nativescript - weird page crash in ios

Tags: nativescript

Got an app and works on Android and iOS.

There's one particular page in the app when I visit crashes in  the production version of iOS app. Works fine in the emulator, works on the device in debug mode.

I narrowed it down to nativescript-imagepicker plugin. Even though no plugin specific code is being executed when the page is opened - it crashes as long as include the plug-in and have the code in a function (not called). If I comment out the code (but still include the plugin) - that works also.

What could cause such a problem?

Does the NS back-end run some code if the plugin is referenced in the page file?

Again works fine in emulator on iOS and also when tested directly on the device.

The problem occurs when the app is downloaded from itunesconnect - so there's no way for me to test it - console messages etc.

Using NS 3.2 with nativescript-imagepicker 0.3.6.

Comment: the latest version of nativescript-imagepicker is  3.0.7 .. are you sure you are working with 0.3.6  - if so try updating to the latest one as it will be compatible with NativeScript 3.x.x.

Comment: imagepicker 0.3.7 has a dependency on the telerilk ui plugin (sp?) - I'd prefer not to load that entire plugin for this feature.